# Hello World [WPF]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am trying to create my hello world windows app in WPF.

What should I do to run this window?

### Class1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Grid>    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Class1.xaml" >
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

### Program.cs

```
class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            new App().Run();
        }
    }
```

I have created a blank sln and added these three files. I have also added WindowsBase, PresentationBase, PresentationFramework refs.

But the App is not running.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to have a `Main` method, your App.xaml file will be ignored.

App.xaml is only used if you set its Build Action to be `ApplicationDefinition`. When you do this, you'll notice you get a compiler error, as you'll have two entry points into your program -- so you'll have to lose the `Main` method.

If you want to keep your `Main` method, you can. Don't change the Build Action on App.xaml (actually, I think you can delete it), and do something like this:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    App app = new App();
    app.StartupUri = new System.Uri("/Project1;component/Class1.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);                     
    app.Run();
}
```

Replace the `/Project1` with your namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new WPF Application would be the way to go, but I may know one way of fixing it.

Your project file probably currently has a section that looks like this:

```
<Page Include="App.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
```

You'll need to change it to use `ApplicationDefinition` instead of `Page`, similar to this:

```
<ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</ApplicationDefinition>
```

This way your project should know what to actually start when you run your application.

The solution I pulled this from was a VS2010 solution, but I think it's the same in VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WPF project?